# Surjections, Bijections, and Injections

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let a and b be real numbers. Consider a function $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ given by the formula $f(x) = ax + b$.

(a) Under what conditions on $a$ and $b$ is $f$ a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? (For instance, what if $a = 0$?)

(b) Under what conditions on $a$ and $b$ is the restriction $f|\mathbb{Z}$ a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$?

(c) Under what conditions on $a$ and $b$ is the restriction $f|\mathbb{N}$ a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$?

My answers:

(a) The function $f$ is a bijection if and only if $a \neq 0$.

(b) The necessary and sufficient condition is that $a = \pm1$.

(c) a = 0 (I'm not sure)

Am I correct? If not, please give me some explanations on the restriction? What is a restriction? How can I solve the problem? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a), (b) are correct.

For (c) you have to take $a=\pm1$ for the same reason in (b), but for $f(x)=-x+b$ where $x,b \in \mathbb{N}$ you don't have the pre-image of $2b \in \mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{N}$. So $a=1$ and $f(x)=x+b$, again if $b\geq1$ you again don't have the pre-image of $1$. So we must have $b=0$ and $f(x)=x~~~\forall~x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

(a) is wrong, in fact, it is as wrong as could be, to the point where I suspect you just made a typo. (b) is correct, but (c) isn't. $f(x) = x + 1$ is not a bijection on the naturals.

Edit: (a) has been corrected.

Comment: Sorry, could you please tell me why (a) is wrong?

Comment: @hanamontana if a = 0, the function is just a straight line parallel to the x-axis, then the only value it has in the range is b, therefore it is not surjective; it is not injective as well

Comment: In other words, f is bijective if and only if a≠0

Comment: Sorry everyone, my typo. Thanks @user20672!

Comment: for c, a = 0 is the answer, right? We would have f(x) = b so it is both surjective and injective (coz the value of x does not matter).

Comment: $f(x)=b$ is a constant function, it's neither surjective nor injective.